# Null data posted on sending JSON string generated from dynamic table

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I am generating a table dynamically in my ASP.NET MVC 4 application. The table is having input boxes in the columns. I have to save the data from these Input boxes. The table generated is [image]

On click of the save button above, I am reading data from table in jquery as

```
    var estimDetails = $('#editorRows tr:has(td)').map(function (i, v) {
                         var $td = $('td', this);
                         return {
                             ItemId: $($td[0]).find("select").val(),
                             Description: $($td[1]).find("input").val(),
                             Quantity: $($td[2]).find("input").val(),
                             Amount: $($td[3]).find("input").val()
                         }
                     }).get();
    //Convert data to JSON
    var estimateObject = JSON.stringify({ 'JsonString': estimDetails });
//post data to Controller Action
 $.ajax({
                 type: 'POST',
                 url: '@Url.Action("SaveEstimate")',
                 data: estimateObject,
                dataType: 'json',
                 contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                 success: function (data) {
                     if (data)
                         alert("Saved Successfully");
                 },
                 error: function (response) {
                     debugger;
                     alert(response);
                 }
             });
```

On inspecting 'estimateObject' has the value as
[image]

My action method is

```
  [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult SaveEstimate(string JsonString)
        {
            try
            {
                DateTime expDate;
                DateTime expiryDt = new DateTime();


                return Json("true", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                return Json("false", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

But the 'JsonString'  is always null. I tried different things like keeping the string inside a ViewModel  in the controller but no help. Kindly help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either try to do this

```
 [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult SaveEstimate(string id) 
        {
            try
            {
                DateTime expDate;
                DateTime expiryDt = new DateTime();


                return Json("true", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                return Json("false", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

or in AJAX call

```
$.ajax({
                 type: 'POST',
                 url: '@Url.Action("SaveEstimate")',
                 data: "JsonString=" + estimateObject,
                 dataType: 'json',                    
                 success: function (data) {
                     if (data)
                         alert("Saved Successfully");
                 },
                 error: function (response) {
                     debugger;
                     alert(response);
                 }
             });
```

Comment: thanks but either option does not work. The first one still gives the value null and the 2nd one gives the error 'Invalid JSON primitive: JsonString.'

Comment: did you set datatype as well ?

Comment: No, can you guide me please.

Comment: Look at ajax call. In my example I have put datatype as text. Whatever data post as a string to controller call. If you put datatype='json' then you don't have to convert json to string. So just try  to set datatype='text'

Comment: Got that to work, but also had to remove the contentType parameter from the ajax call. Thanks a lot. So, kindly edit you answer so that I can mark it :)

Comment: ContentType is useful when you post data and data type is response you want.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that use from this code

```
 public  Class Estimate{
    public int ItemId{get;set;}
    public string Description{get;set;}
    public int Quantity{get;set;}
    public int Amount{get;set;}

    }
```

And in Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SaveEstimate(Estimate model) 
    {
      //To Do
    }
```

And in Client Code

```
      var estimDetails = $('#editorRows tr:has(td)').map(function (i, v) {
                         var $td = $('td', this);
                         return {
                             ItemId: $($td[0]).find("select").val(),
                             Description: $($td[1]).find("input").val(),
                             Quantity: $($td[2]).find("input").val(),
                             Amount: $($td[3]).find("input").val()
                         }
                     }).get();
    //Convert data to JSON
    var estimateObject = JSON.stringify({ 'model': estimDetails });
//post data to Controller Action
 $.ajax({
                 type: 'POST',
                 url: '@Url.Action("SaveEstimate")',
                 data: estimateObject,
                dataType: 'json',
                 contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                 success: function (data) {
                     if (data)
                         alert("Saved Successfully");
                 },
                 error: function (response) {
                     debugger;
                     alert(response);
                 }
             });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you send $().ajax your controller action parse by name input HTTP parameters into C# method parameters.
To send data in $().ajax used data option

```
 $.ajax({
                 type: 'POST',
                 url: '@Url.Action("SaveEstimate")',
                 data: {someData:'sss'}   //Look here
             });
```

When ajax sended, javaScript object, that you put to data, parsed by member to HTTp parameters (every field of Object put to parameter name to name, value to value).

So in my example there is someData HTTP parameter with value 'sss'.
In Action MVC try find HTTP parameters called like C# method parameters and automaticaly set values of theirs.

In your code MVC expect parameter  JsonString of type String, but $().ajax send a string (after stringify an json) in data, so jQuery create a HTTP parameter data and put a string value to it.

To make your code work you must do the folowing:

Stringify only payload data

```
var estimateObject = { 'JsonString': JSON.stringify(estimDetails) };
```

Send in ajax your result object simply

```
$.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: '@Url.Action("SaveEstimate")',
             data: estimateObject,
             success: function (data) {
                 if (data)
                     alert("Saved Successfully");
             },
             error: function (response) {
                 debugger;
                 alert(response);
             }
         });
```

Thus, jQuery lookup to estimateObject, find in it only one field JsonObject, create same HTTP parameter and send to server.
MVC lookup in HTTP parameters for parameter JsonObject, find it and set value of C# method parameter with name JsonObject value with stringify JSON.